# Bindling shortcut keys in UDK

Tags: unrealscript

sorry for my poor english first.

i wrote a function to switch view(third person--first person).

i have already change the content in UDKInput.ini like

```
Bindings=(Name="PageDown",Command="CameraThirdPers on")

Bindings=(Name="PageUp",Command="CameraFirstPerson ")
```

and also write the function in my custom pawn class file to switch the view.

all thing looks great, but ,when i packaged the game, i find that my "PageDown" and "PageUp" key didn't work!

i dont know how to soul this soultion!

sorry for my poor wirting again!

thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the console (tilde key) and enter the commands, do they work?

If not, then the problem is with your commands. Make sure the functions are marked 'exec', and that your game is set up to actually use your custom pawn class.

If the commands do work, than the problem is in the ini file. Make sure there are no bindings for PageDown and PageUp further down in the list (you could move your bindings to the end of the list), as I believe later bindings override earlier ones. If that doesn't solve the problem, your bindings may be in the wrong section. Try opening the console and entering:

```
setbind pagedown camerathirdperson
```

If the PageDown key then works the way you want it to, exit the game and see where the game saved the new binding in the ini file.